# Groovy regex parse value

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I am trying to parse the below item using regex

Input field is

```
def details = "jurisdictionOfIncorporationCountryName=GB, l=Cheshunt, st=Herts, c=GB"
```

Output needed is

- Location = Chesthunt
- state = Herts
- Country = GB

Code which i tried to retreive  the state is

```
def location= subject =~/([l][=])\w+/
```

I am getting this as output when i print the location value

```
r[pattern=([l][=])\w+ region=0,192 lastmatch=l=Cheshunt]
```

I tried using the parse method

```
if (location) {

   location = location[0][0]

}
```

I am getting the output as l=chesthunt where i need to get only the chesthunt. Could you please assist as i am new to groovy/regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
def details = "jurisdictionOfIncorporationCountryName=GB, l=Cheshunt, st=Herts, c=GB"
```

You can do:

```
def location = details.find(~/l=([^\s,]+)/) { it[1] }
```

this `~/l=([^\s,]+)/` looks for something starting with `l=`, and then captures up until whitespace or a comma

Comment: it made my day. thanks a lot and it is really helpful and easy to understand

Comment: My pleasure!  Have fun!